# Python:winreg module :Windows 7:None is not valid HKEY error

Tags: python, winreg

I ran into issues while reading registry value for windows 7 winth winreg module .Any pointers to resolve the same?

Code :

```
try:
    ParentKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
    i = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = _winreg.EnumValue(ParentKey, i)
        print repr(name),
        i += 1

except Exception as e:
    print(Exception(e))

ParentKey =_winreg.DisableReflectionKey(ParentKey)    
temp = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ParentKey, 'DisplayName')
temp1 = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ParentKey, 'DisplayVersion')
temp2 = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ParentKey, 'Publisher')
temp3 = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ParentKey, 'InstallLocation')

display = str(temp[0])
display_ver=str(temp1[0])
display_p=str(temp2[0])
display_loc=str(temp3)
print ('Display Name: ' + display + '\nDisplay version:  ' + display_ver + '\nVendor/Publisher:  ' + display_p +'\nRegkey: ' + display_loc +'\nInstall Location: ' )
```

Output:

```
[Error 259] No more data is available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Test\workspace\Pythontests\src\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    temp = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ParentKey, 'DisplayName')
TypeError: None is not a valid HKEY in this context
**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ParentKey = _winreg.DisableReflectionKey(ParentKey)
```

will return `None`. The function `DisableReflectionKey` is not documented as returning anything (success or failure is indicated by whether or not an exception is raised). Such a function that does not return anything returns `None` implicitly. Since you bind the returned value to `ParentKey`, that variable will holds `None` from that point on.

So, of course the subsequent call,

```
_winreg.QueryValueEx(ParentKey, 'DisplayName')
```

will fail since `QueryValueEx` requires a defined key (not `None`) to work.